# JAVA Null Pointer Exception running JAR

Tags: java

I am trying to run my jar file on a different machine(not on the dev machine). Running it gives me a null exception, while running on the dev machine runs as expected. Really don't get why. This is the line i am getting the exception on :

currentSapt = Integer.parseInt(saptamanaCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());

Where 'currentSapt' is int and 'saptamnaCombo' is a Combo Box. Any help would be much appreciated. [image]

```
public class VizualizareScreen extends JPanel{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Connection connection;
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private JScrollPane tableScroll;
    private GridBagConstraints c;
    private JLabel saptamanaLabel2;
    private JLabel mancareLabel2;
    private JLabel scoalaLabel2;
    private JComboBox<Integer> saptamanaCombo;
    private Font font;
    private Font totalFont;
    private Integer[] saptamani;
    private int currentSapt;
    private int totalMancare;
    private int totalScoala;
    private JButton modifica;
    private JButton sterge;
    private JLabel numeLabel;
    private JLabel prenumeLabel;
    private JLabel mancareLabel;
    private JLabel scoalaLabel;
    private JLabel dataLabel;
    private JLabel saptamanaLabel;
    private JTextField numeField;
    private JTextField prenumeField;
    private JComboBox<String> mancareCombo;
    private JComboBox<String> scoalaCombo;
    private JTextField dataField;
    private JTextField saptamanaField;
    private String modifiedNume;
    private String modifiedPrenume;
    private String modifiedData;
    private Font fieldsFont;
    private Font buttonFont;
    private int deleteId;
    public JComboBox<Integer> getSaptamanaCombo() {
        return saptamanaCombo;
    }
    public VizualizareScreen(Connection conn) {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        initComponents(conn);
        populate(Integer.parseInt(saptamanaCombo.getSelectedItem().toString()));
        mancareLabel2.setText(mancareLabel2.getText() + totalMancare);
        scoalaLabel2.setText(scoalaLabel2.getText() + totalScoala);
        addComponents();    
    }
    public void initComponents(Connection conn){
        connection = conn;
        modifiedNume = "";
        modifiedPrenume = "";
        modifiedData = "";
        int sapt = getSaptamani(), saptCount = 0;;
        saptamani = new Integer[sapt];
        for(int i = 1; i <= sapt; i++)
            saptamani[saptCount++] = i;
        font = new Font("Times New Roman",Font.PLAIN,20);
        totalFont = new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,32);
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        String[] items = {"DA","NU"};
        mancareLabel2 = new JLabel("Mancare: ");
        mancareLabel2.setFont(totalFont);
        scoalaLabel2 = new JLabel("Scoala: ");
        scoalaLabel2.setFont(totalFont);
        saptamanaLabel2 = new JLabel("Saptamana: ");
        saptamanaLabel2.setFont(font);
        saptamanaCombo = new JComboBox<Integer>(saptamani);
        saptamanaCombo.setSelectedIndex(saptamanaCombo.getItemCount()-1);
        saptamanaCombo.setFont(font);   
        fieldsFont = new Font("Times New Roman",Font.PLAIN,20);
        numeField = new JTextField(20);
        numeField.setFont(fieldsFont);
        prenumeField = new JTextField(20);
        prenumeField.setFont(fieldsFont);
        mancareCombo = new JComboBox<String>(items);
        mancareCombo.setFont(fieldsFont);
        scoalaCombo = new JComboBox<String>(items);
        scoalaCombo.setFont(fieldsFont);
        saptamanaField = new JTextField(20);
        saptamanaField.setFont(fieldsFont);
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
        String currentDate = ft.format(new Date());
        dataField = new JTextField(20);
        dataField.setFont(fieldsFont);
        dataField.setText(currentDate);
        buttonFont = new Font("Times New Roman",Font.PLAIN,50);
        currentSapt = Integer.parseInt(saptamanaCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Comment: Could you provide the source code?

Comment: Please keep working on improving this question. As written, it remains extremely difficult to answer and risks being closed.

Comment: Done. Just a part of it, adding it all would be irrelevant

Comment: No, we don't want to see all, just a small runnable sub-set that shows us your error, a [mcve]. Concentrate on what you're putting into that combo box and where you're doing it.

Comment: Check what is assigned to the variable in the line ``int sapt = getSaptamani()``. If that is ``0`` its probably the reason for the following NPE.

Comment: The questions is why does it work on my machine, but on on other ? Same code

Comment: You're going to want to use a log file to query the state of everything as the program runs on various machines. Question: are you using images or files anywhere? Does the jar hold data files?

Comment: I am connecting to a mysql database

Comment: As for files, i am using just a conector library

Answer (score 0):

As @f1sh pointed out - this error most likely occurs from `getSaptamani()` returning 0.

You could still work around this by modifying your logic a bit (not saying it will run much further than that line...)

Currently your code for selecting currentSapt looks like this:

```
int sapt = getSaptamani(), saptCount = 0;;
saptamani = new Integer[sapt];
for(int i = 1; i <= sapt; i++)
        saptamani[saptCount++] = i;
saptamanaCombo = new JComboBox<Integer>(saptamani);
saptamanaCombo.setSelectedIndex(saptamanaCombo.getItemCount()-1);
currentSapt = Integer.parseInt(saptamanaCombo.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

So basically `saptamani[n] = n+1` and ComboBox shows values 1,...,n and selected item in combo should be the last item `n` and currentSapt should equally hold that largest value `n`. As this largest item n is exactly what you get back grom `getSamtamani()`, you could rewrite to

```
    int sapt = getSaptamani();
    saptamani = new Integer[sapt];
    for(int i = 1; i <= sapt; i++) {
        saptamani[i-1] = i;
    }
    saptamanaCombo = new JComboBox<Integer>(saptamani);
    saptamanaCombo.setSelectedIndex(saptamanaCombo.getItemCount()-1);

    currentSapt = sapt; //Last value = sapt
```

This should get rid of the nasty NPE - but your issue is most likely locates in getSamtamani() returning 0 as initially said.